# How best to determine JSON null Variant in a Java UDF?

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

In a Java UDF I want to determine whether a Variant value is a JSON null but it seems the only way to do it is to convert it to a Json String and compare it to the string "null". Since I am working with values that may be very large, converting the value to a json string just to check for null seems wasteful. Is there not a better way?

```java
// Current
boolean isNull = variant.asJsonString().equals("null");
 
// Preferred
boolean isNull = variant.isNull();
```

It looks like Variants contain a Jackson JsonNode instance internally. Could there be a pass-thru that calls JsonNode.isNull() ?

From https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D5Do00000D7rgsKAB/how-best-to-determine-json-null-variant-in-a-java-udf.

Comment: Deleting my answer, as it doesn't satisfy for a JSON null, as in `select java_variant_isnull(parse_json('{"a":null}'))`